# On MacOS10.14 Mojave, When I access Camera, it will ask for permission twice

Tags: macos, permissions, camera

recently I upgraded my MacOS to Mojave, after archiving my App, I opened it. but I found when it tried to access the camera, it will ask permission twice.
on the other hand, when I run my project with Xcode, it will only request permission once.
I have added "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" to info.plist file.

anyone has met this ?
any comments will be appreciated.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKktr.jpg)